# fingerprint sensor: authentication fails and fingerprint disappears afterwards

Tags: dell, 22.04, xps, fingerprint-reader

I just purchased a dell xps 13 with ubuntu. The fingerprint sensor worked fine. Then, I created a backup disk using Dell Recovery Tool and reinstalled ubuntu (as I wanted to enable Full Disk Encryption). Now, the following problem appears which I am unable to solve:

- I register a new fingerprint
- The fingerprint shows up as saved
- I try to use it, for sudo in a terminal or for login
- This immediately  fails
- All saved fingerprints are gone afterwards

I also tried to do everything via command line to discover any errors.

- `fprintd-enroll` works well
- `fprintd-list <username>` lists the fingerprint
- `fprintd-verify` immediately fails (verfiy-no-match)
- afterwards, `fprind-list` no longer lists the fingerprint

Any I idea why it stopped working after resinstall and (more importantly), how to fix this?
(Ubuntu version is 22.04 LTS)

Comment: Usually when you get a Dell computer with Ubuntu preinstalled they have made some changes. What did you reinstall from? You may be missing some drivers.

Comment: I used a program preinstalled by Dell on my computer (Dell Recovery Tool). It says that "This will integrate Dell OEM FID-Framework and drivers into a custom system image." I booted from this image and reinstalled, so I would expect to have all drivers dell delivers with the laptop (and the fingerprint reader is getting detected, there just is the issue that verification is not possible and makes the fingerprints disappear).

Comment: Time to contact Dell support I would suggest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve it without contacting Dell support, add to `etc/apt/sources.list.d/` a file with the following content:

```
deb http://dell.archive.canonical.com/ focal somerville
# deb-src http://dell.archive.canonical.com/ focal somerville
deb http://dell.archive.canonical.com/ focal somerville-bulbasaur
# deb-src http://dell.archive.canonical.com/ focal somerville-bulbasaur
deb http://oem.archive.canonical.com/ focal oem
#deb-src http://oem.archive.canonical.com/ focal oem
```

Then run `sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys F9FDA6BED73CDC22`. Afterwards, the driver for the fingerprint sensor shows up under "additional drivers".

(This solution is due to the german c't magazine and was originally found
[here](https://ct.de/y54z).)